# My error is: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, web-development-server

I am trying to output the `result` in a handlebars file, when i run the server, everything runs perfectly, but when i check the browser, it shows 
`[object Object]` and then in the console it writes the following error: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

What is the issue and how can i solve it?

```
const express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var http = require("http");
const net  = require('net');
const Web3 = require('web3');
var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.IpcProvider("/home/terry/.ether1/geth.ipc",net))
console.log(web3.isConnected()) // return true if connected

web3.version.getNetwork((error, result) => {
    console.log('The result is: ' + result)
});

app.get('/', function (req, res, result) {
    res.render('index',{
        title: result
    });
});

app.listen(50000)
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:50000/');
```

I want the `title: result` to be output the way its meant to be, and not as `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result` in this function: `function (req, res, result)` is not a result it's `next()` function you can't use it like this

Try something like this

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    web3.version.getNetwork((error, result) => {
     res.render('index',{
        title: result
     });
    });

});
```